# Class "\Core\App\AppRouter" not found

Tags: php, clase, diseño-de-clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando **PHP** y **XAMPP**. Al cambiar el nombre de la carpeta donde está alojado el programa en `htdocs`, me aparece este error al intentar correr el programa. **"SIACRM"** es el nombre de la nueva carpeta, antes tenía un nombre distinto. Me aseguré de cambiar el nombre de cada clase por **SIACRAM**, por ejemplo:

```php
namespace Siacrm\Core\App;

use Siacrm\Core\Base\MyFilesToken;

use Siacrm\Core\Base\PluginManager;
```

Pero el programa no corre con el nuevo nombre que le he puesto a la carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando composer para cargar las clases. Despues de un cambio en las rutas (directorios) tienes que reiniciar composer.
Colocate en el directorio raiz de tu proyecto (donde esta tu composer.json) y en tu terminal ejecuta `composer dump-autoload` o `composer dumpautoload`. Cualquiera de los dos comandos funciona.